# PHP session management by id

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

So my goal here is to manage the users through session id, so to do that

1. Check clients cookie if there is a old session id, if not ask server for a new one and save in clients cookie, else take the id and request the server to resume a session with that id.

Code:

```
 session_id($_POST["SESSID"]);     
 session_start();
```

2.use the session id in every request to fetch users data.

but i have two concerns:

1. isnt it unsecure to allow the client to provide a session id for the server? wont that open the application for abuse, where people will try guess others users session id?
2. wont the server lose the control of which session are expired? as long the client have the old session id , they can use it forever ?

**EDIT: a possible solution:**
So to adress my concerns, i modifed the code, to set a an expiration date to every session id, and if the old session ID is expired then the server sets a new one for the client, like the following:

```
session_id($_POST['SESSID']);
session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['expires']) && $_SESSION['expires'] > time()){
  //use old session
}else{
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id(true);
  $_SESSION['expires'] = date(strtotime("+1 hour"));
  // use new session
}
```

Comment: Its probably not a good idea to do that, for the concerns you raised. PHP still cleans up old session files (or the server does), so even trying to reference an old session id, will result in no variables set. You should use a database for user management. Sessions are best for temporary logged in data between scripts in a single sitting.

Comment: Also, even with users in a db, there is still a real possibility someone is trying to guess at cookie values to 'hijack' someones session ;) If security is a concern, there are libraries out there to help ease the pain of rolling your own solution (and worrying if you got it secure enough).

Answer (score 1):

This vulnerability even has a name. :) It's called [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).

**Edit:**

To avoid session fixation and related session vulnerabilities, you should

- not assign sessions to anonymous users (sessions take resources)
- whenever privilege levels change, and most importantly, when a user logs in, assign a new session id (if there was already one, reassign a new one)
- always generate session ids on the server, never take a session id from a client
- use the built in session management features (as opposed to things like generating your own session id)
- use a reasonable session timeout, both sliding and absolute, depending on your business case

Note that this is not a comprehensive list, and it is in no particular order.

Comment: but i dont really see how it different from the way the php handles session bu default which is by setting the session id in cookie. so if someone get his hand of a users cookie then they can authencate themselfs as the victim ? so could we assume PHP sessions are in secure ?

Comment: I added a solution to my orginal post which i think is safe, what do u think ?

Comment: "create a session with a known id on the computer of the victim user" --- this needs a serious rework. At this moment is looks misleading and wrong.

Comment: @zerkms Can you please elaborate? Maybe it's a wording issue in my answer, in which case, sorry for that. :)

Comment: @zerkms Ah ok, the question changed. I will remove that whole paragraph, thanks.

Comment: @pabloBar Why do you want to take the initial session id from a cookie? Why not just generate it new when needed, and regenerate upon login? If there is a valid session id in the cookie, that will be used anyway, so what's the point?

Comment: @GaborLengyel it totally was just wording indeed. It sounded like the sessions are created/stored on the clients machines.

Comment: @zerkms Reading again, it really did, thank you for pointing it out. With the current version of the question, it became less relevant anyway, so I will just leave that part deleted.

Comment: @GaborLengyel the i reason set the session id in cookie and manage it manually is because i keep my frontend and backend seperated, so when i want to get the session data for a user via AJAX call, a new id generate for each call, even if a user have a valid session, the server just spawns a new one. so as a work around, i let the server assign a user a session id then save it on the client so whenever i do call to the backend, i send the session id in the call to the server, to fetch correct session data

Comment: @pabloBar are you not missing withCredentials for the ajax call? [See here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) I don't see why you should be hacking it the way you described. You should just use the standard session management.

Comment: intersting, but i dont see it working. because the user never visit the a php page, so there is really no possiblity for the client to receive a session cookie from the server, its my frontend that handles communication with the backend